# Node Canvas - npm error when trying to install packages

Tags: reactjs, npm, canvas, homebrew, npm-install

I am getting errors when trying to run the "npm install" in the terminal, for a work project I have cloned. It is a React project that is built using Vite.

When I run the command, I am getting errors relating to libffi, I have it installed with home brew and even re-installed and when doing so have even run the path config command

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I have also tried using the --force flag with npm install and still no luck.

I have visited the canvas npm page - https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas?activeTab=readme
and run their brew install command

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman
```

I'll share the npm error and my homebrew list

```
    cairo                   giflib                  jpeg                    libtiff                 libxrender              pkg-config
    fontconfig              git                     jpeg-turbo              libx11                  lz4                     xorgproto
    freetype                glib                    libffi                  libxau                  lzo                     xz
    fribidi                 graphite2               libpng                  libxcb                  pango                   zlib
    gdk-pixbuf              harfbuzz                libpthread-stubs        libxdmcp                pcre2                   zstd
    gettext                 icu4c                   librsvg                 libxext                 pixman
```

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN deprecated @vitest/coverage-c8@0.24.5: v8 coverage is moved to @vitest/coverage-v8 package
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/hdhillon016/React/RelCheckWebUI/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.8 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/hdhillon016/React/RelCheckWebUI/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/hdhillon016/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/hdhillon016/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/hdhillon016/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.15.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/hdhillon016/React/RelCheckWebUI/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! Package 'libffi', required by 'gobject-2.0', not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --cflags-only-I | sed s/-I//g' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:261:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/hdhillon016/React/RelCheckWebUI/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried re-installing the home brew packages, lowering any firewalls, running the path config command when installing libffi manually.